# c# Increment number within a string

Tags: c#, regex, string, increment

I need to print all emails from 001 to 100. For example `test+001@gmail.com` till `test+100@gmail.com`
I'm trying to use a Regex and I separate the number I need to increment by 1 but I don't know how to structure the for loop.

```
string email = "test+001@gmail.com";

Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d+");  
var parts = email.Split('@');
string prefix = Regex.Replace(email, @"\d+", "");
```

Comment: What about the input 001test001@top100.com?

Comment: why not use string interpolation?  `email = $"test+{number}@gmail.com"`

Comment: @GeestWagen: if that's the solution, I guess you need to explain where `number` comes from.

Comment: If `string email = "test+001@gmail.com";`is not a required input, you should probably mention that the input is not necessarily in that format.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it without regex actually, by iterating numbers from `1` to `100` in a loop, and use [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) to add a number to email template

```cs
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
{
    var email = $"test+{i:000}@gmail.com";
    Console.WriteLine(email);
}
```

The important point here is `{i:000}` format with leading 0s

Comment: Potentially, test+001@gmail.com is some user input from command line or so and was just used as an example

Comment: Thank you, this works. I was trying with Regex and I got confused.

Comment: He also didn't mention that he can change it arbitrarily.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string email = "test+{0:D3}@gmail.com";
        for (int i = 1; i < 101; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format(email, i));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> ```
> test+001@gmail.com
> test+002@gmail.com
> test+003@gmail.com
> // etc etc
> ```

Comment: Phew, you're lucky that the output is only 100 lines long. Does listing the complete output provide any benefit?

Answer (score 1):

I kinda like the simplicity of just using `Enumerable.Range`:

```
foreach(int i in Enumerable.Range(1, 100))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"test+{i:000}@gmail.com");
}
```

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6TtWkw)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do it like this ?

```
var n = 0;
while(n++ != 100)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"test+{n}@gmail.com");
}
```

Insted of increasing the number from string, you just recreate the string each time.

Answer (score 0):

This handles the leading zeros

```
string email = "test+001@gmail.com";

Regex.Replace(email, @"\d{1,3}", (mtch) =>
{
    return (mtch.Success) ? (int.Parse(mtch.Value) + 1).ToString("D3") : string.Empty;

});
```

Replace returns `test+002@gmail.com` and other values up to 999.

Answer (score 0):

Using Linq.

```
var x=Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Select(x => "test"+x.ToString("000")+"@gmail.com");
```